# How to convert a comma separated string into json array using MySQL and Go

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a table named `Product` with a JSON column called `data`. Inside `data` there is a property called `formerIds`, which is a comma separated list stored as string.

```json
{
    "formerIds": "12345,54321,09876"
}
```

The ids are previous ids of a product. I want to be able to search for any of those ids quickly. My idea is to convert the comma separated list of ids into a json array and create a multi-valued index in MySQL. So as an example, look at the following

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product (
    productId VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data NOT NULL JSON,
    ...
    formerIds JSON GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_OBJECT('ids', CAST(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(data->>'$.formerIds', ',', '","'), '"]') AS JSON))),
    INDEX product_formerIds_idx (CAST(formerIds->'$.ids' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY))
);
```

This is working fine. The only problem is, that I want to use Golang and GORM to implement it. Here's what I've done so far.

```golang
type Product struct {
    ProductId string         `gorm:"column:productId;index;primaryKey"`
    Data      datatypes.JSON `gorm:"column:data"`
    FormerIds JSON           `gorm:"column:formerIds;index:,expression:CAST(formerIds->'$.ids' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY);type:JSON GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_OBJECT('ids', CAST(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(data->>'$.formerIds', ',', '","'), '"]') AS JSON)))"`
}
```

The problem lies in the structure tags of `Product`, because I want to use double quotes inside the tag value itself to convert the comma separated list into a json array using `CONCAT` and `REPLACE`. I've already tried to escape those quotes, but I can't get it run.

In my opinion, I could solve it by...

1. ... don't use GORM and it's migration mechanism, but my own predefined statements to create and maintain the tables,
2. ... somehow escaping the quotes in the structure tags,
3. ... using other SQL statements for the string conversion to prevent using double quotes in structure tags.

Do you have any other ideas or solutions? I've already tried to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `JSON_ARRAYAGG` instead of `CONCAT` and `REPLACE` for the virtual column, but row aggregation is not working there.

Comment: I would not store values as a comma-separated string. Use a second table for formerIds, with one formerId value per row. Then you don't need JSON. Just index the formerId column normally.

Comment: @BillKarwin Great idea, I thought about that, too. I decided against this solution because it also means, that I have to maintain the additional table. For example, whenever the data provider sends updates about any product and the id changes, then I have to run additional logic to keep the table up to date. Feels like it would scale badly.